# Attaching the numbers to the polygon

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Suppose a regular 45-sided polygon  and numbers 0,1,2,...,9. Now attach these numbers to vertices of the polygon such that for any arbitrary pair of numbers (among of 0 to 9) there exist a edge of the polygon that attached with the pair of numbers.

Is it possible that does such attachment to the polygon? How? or why not?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  how many digits does $9$ have to be next to?  How many $9$'s does that mean there are?

Hint2:  $9$ has to be next to $9$ different numbers.

Comment: What do you mean? Note that digits are at arbitrary number from 0, .... 9.

Comment: I understand that.  Can you answer the two questions?

Comment: I did not understand your questions? Please describe them.

Comment: You have asked that $9$ be next to all the other digits (presumably it doesn't have to be next to $9$ itself,based on the number $45$). How many is that? Each $9$ can only be next to two other numbers. That gives you a minimum number of vertices that are assigned to $9$. Is anything special about $9$?

Comment: No, nothing. There is no restriction on multiplicity 9 or other numbers or place of numbers on vertices.

Comment: You still haven't thought about how many $9$'s must be in the diagram.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11779/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-bigli)